# Can we run multiple modules in ansible using single ad-hoc command?

Tags: ansible, ansible-ad-hoc

I know it's possible to run multiple adhoc commands one after the other for each module and using playbook.

Playbook:

---

```
- hosts: webservers
  tasks:
   - name: create .ssh dir
     file: path ~/.ssh state=directory
   - name: copy pub key
     copy: src:~/.ssh/id.rsa_pub dest=~/.ssh/authorized_keys
```

I want the above to execute using adhoc in one line. Is it possible to do so?

Comment: I don' think so. I think it is restricted only from one module (-m) at a time. May I know why you are interested in this? Any specific use case?

Comment: No use case as of such. Just exploring new things.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

No, it is not possible.

`ansible` command accepts only one set of arguments for a single module and its parameters.

> `-m MODULE_NAME, --module-name=MODULE_NAME`
>   module name to execute (default=`command`)

Comment: This prevents ad-hoc modules from running, wich depend on facts

Answer (score 1):

Use ansible-console and heredoc instead:

```
ansible-console <<<"cd webservers"$'\n'"setup"$'\n'"file path=~/.ssh state=directory"$'\n'"copy src=~/.ssh/id.rsa_pub dest=~/.ssh/authorized_keys"
```

This is technically one hack of a line but has no error handling.
And is pretty not readable.

`ansible-console` alone eventually could do the trick. It's a pretty neat tool.

Answer (score -2):

We can actually use the below single ad-hoc command using Ansible module and Linux command:

```
ansible clientvm -m shell -a "mkdir ~/.ssh" && scp ~/.ssh/id_rsa.pub root@clientvm:~/.ssh/authorized_keys
```

In the above command, `clientvm` is the hostname where we are creating the directory and copying the file into it as per above requirement from the Ansible controller node.

Comment: This is not a single command, it is 2 commands where the 2nd depends on the exit code of the first. The OP asked for a single command.